# Is there an algorithm that can solve chess within the span of a human lifetime?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, search-algorithms, board-games

According to Shannon (in his 1949 paper) the game of chess has too much complexity to be solved by a brute-force search of the game tree:

> A machine... would require over $10^{90}$ years to calculate the first move!

But his paper ends with a section entitled "Another Type of Strategy" and provides vague guidance on other options to solve chess.

Can it be proven whether chess can or cannot be solved with some algorithm (other than brute force) within some defined amount of time (for example, 100 years)?

Comment: Computers have sped up a lot since 1949. It's probably down to $10^{80}$ now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prove that chess can't be solved with less than 100 years time because you don't know what computers will be developed during that time. The only limits on computational speed we know are [pretty ridiculous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits_of_computation#Physical_limits) compared to what we can do today.

You might be able to prove that solving chess needs at least X many operations, but I don't know of any such results.

Comment: I also don't know if any work has been done to find the lower bounds for the number of operations required to solve chess. Shannon (in 1949) gave us some information on applying a brute-force evaluation. Unfortunately, his calculations give us no information on the lower limit for other types of analytical solution methods.

Btw, the link you provided for the limits of computation is interesting, but in general, those bounds apply to technology that more than likely will require more than 100 years to become viable (i.e. "use a black hole as a data storage or computing device").

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

Well, maybe not in the span of a human lifetime yet, but there are lots of algorithms that given enough time, they would provide an answer!

Knowing if a problem is solvable or not doesn't depend on the amount of resources or people working on it, it only depends on the problem itself. It is a solvable problem, and it could eventually be solved. It's just that it's such a hard problem that it would take too long, and you would need an enourmous amount of memory. But even if you had only one person, or a team of millions of people, they could eventually find a way to always win the game.

Comment: My question doesn't pertain to yet. My question pertains to ever. If we had 100,000 researchers, and 100,000 programmers, and 100,000 mathematicians who specialize in game theory, and they had access to a large number of supercomputers, would their work be futile? Or is there a possibility they can solve chess?

Comment: Of course. Knowing if a problem is solvable or not doesn't depend on the amount of resources or people working on it, it only depends on the problem itself. It is a solvable problem, and it could eventually be solved. It's just that it's such a hard problem that it would take too long, and you would need an enourmous amount of memory. But they could (even tho they could find out that there is no way to always win, which would be as futile as not being able to find any answer whatsoever)

Comment: That's what I thought. I believe your newer comment is a better answer than the initial comment that you provided as an answer. (i.e your supplemental comment pertains to the question, whereas your original answer did not). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Btw, learning that neither side has a way to win means that both sides can force a draw. So that is one of the possible answers to solving a game.

Comment: That's a bit complicated huh... If the computer played against a human, the game would probably end up in a state that would make the comp win. Being both computers, making the best move, they could end up always drawing... We don't know yet, so let's wait for a few more years to know if there's a solution to chess or not c:

Comment: I can't see hows this is a answer. It seems that Shannon already showed that it is possible to calculate the first move given enough time. You say that there are other algorithms that can this, too, given enough time. But you cannot say, how much time. It is not really a surprise that there are improvement to exhaustive seatch or other algorithms, that solve the problem.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Do you know if there is an algorithm that can solve chess within the span of a human lifetime? That's the question that I'm trying to have answered.

Comment: The problem isn't that there isn't an algorithm, because there are many strategies to achieve your goal. The problem here is that technology isn't as advanced as necessary, and honestly, I don't think any supercomputer in this world will be left unusable for years while it's trying to solve chess. But there is an algorithm, that's for sure.

Comment: I think that's ambiguous. There are algorithms, but we don't have the technology.

That leaves us where Shannon left is in 1949. Chess will require >10^90 years to solve?

That is not within a person's life-time, so I take this as "No - chess cannot be solved within a person's lifetime".

Comment: well, technology has advanced a lot in 70 years! People back then couldn't imagine that any machine could end up beating a human at tic tac toe. This is a question based on personal opinions more than anything else, becuase as I said, nobody has and will try to explore all the possible games of chess. It takes too long. But maybe not longer than a human life (let's say 80 years). But nobody knows.

Comment: Is it possible that an algorithm exists other than brute force? (i.e. something other than an exhaustive search of the game tree)? It doesn't have to exist today. The possibility just needs to NOT be excluded. In other words, some researchers with access to supercomputers, might sit down today and begin to study the problem, with the knowledge that solving chess is possible within 100 years.

This would be a new statement currently not found in Shannon's paper of 1949. If this is added to the answer (above) then I think it concludes this this question, and I would rate it as "useful".

Comment: Hmmmm... Well you can add lots of restrictions not to make it an absolute brute force algorithm but... Unfortunately, I don't think there is one.

Comment: Well, your words are a bit misleading, that it only depends on problem complexity. There are weak and ultra-weak solutions for various games. Almost surely one can wrie a program that will check correctness on such prove in time smaller than human lifetime.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure if in time smaller than human lifetime, but what's true is that every problem can be solved if you don't take into consideration the time complexity